# В автотесте не добавляется файл через функцию open

Tags: python, файлы, rest

В директории есть папка `files`, в которой лежит файл с названием `football.mp4`.

В папке `configs` у меня лежит `python` файл `post_json.py` в котором я прописываю путь к файлу `football.mp4` с помощью функции `open`

```
video_2 = {
        'video': open('files/football.mp4', 'rb')
    }

post_json_video_with_text = {
            'text': 'TEST POST VIDEO MP4'
        }
```

Затем я импортирую папку `configs` в тест:

```
from endpoints.PostController import PostController
from configs.post_json import *

def test_create_video_post_text():
    request_post_create = PostController().create_post(files=video_2, data=post_json_video_with_text)
    assert request_post_create['status']['statusCodeValue'] == 200
```

После запуска теста с помощью команды

```
pytest
tests/UserStoryTests/test_create_post.py::test_create_video_post_text
```

Мне приход ответ `407`, который говорит о том что файл не добавлен.

Что я делаю не так?

Тоже самое у меня происходит в тесте, где сначала я регистрирую пользователя, а затем меняю аватарку зареганного пользователя. Регистрация проходит успешно, но как только доходит до добавления изображения, оно также не вставляется. Причем если в конце теста я его просто распечатаю используя `print(b)` то вернется 200, тест успешно пройден.

Вот тест:

```
from endpoints.AdminAccountController import AdminAccountController
from configs.admin_account_json import *
from endpoints.ProfileUpdate import ProfileUpdate
from configs.post_json import *
import allure
import pytest


@pytest.mark.parametrize("users, pictures, expected_email, expected_nickname, expected_role",
                         [(user_1, picture_2, "ghgk@jfjs.com", "kukistesting", "ROLE_USER")])
def test_registration_user_create(users, pictures, expected_email, expected_nickname, expected_role):
    c = AdminAccountController().create_account(users)
    assert c['body']['email'] == expected_email and c['body']['nickname'] == expected_nickname \
           and c['body']['role'] == expected_role
    b = ProfileUpdate().update_photo(files=pictures)
    assert b['status']['statusCode'] == 200
```

Я также передаю изображение, используя метод который находится в классе параметра b

Для этого обращаюсь в файл post_json, где лежит путь к изображению, которое находится в папке files:

```
picture_2 = {
    'picture': open('files/patrik.jpg', 'rb')
}
```

Comment: У вас ровно один такой тест или есть ещё тесты, которые используют тот же самый `video_2`?

Comment: Есть еще, они также присылают 407

Comment: Такая же проблема есть и с изображениями, которые я добавляю в другие автотесты
Делаю все тоже самое

Comment: Если вы используете один и тот же файл несколько раз, то после первого использования он считывается до конца, и последующие операции чтения будут возвращать пустоту, из-за чего второй и последующие тесты будут ломаться. Нужно или отматывать файл на начало с помощью seek, или переоткрывать файл заново между тестами

Comment: Насколько я знаю, так происходит, когда запускаешь тест через кнопку тест рана, а если запустить через команду:
"pytest tests/UserStoryTests/test_create_post.py::test_create_video_post_text"
то тест будет всегда будет брать файл который находится в директории.
Но в любом случае, даже при первом запуске у мне приходит 407 и файл не подставляется в тест

Comment: А какой у вас текущий каталог получается при запуске этого кода? Помните, что текущий каталог вовсе не обязан совпадать с каталогом, в котором лежит запускаемый код, он может оказаться совсем другим.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы указываете путь относительно родительской папки текущего модуля, то можно через `__file__` получить полный путь к самому модулю теста, получить родительскую папку, потом относительно нее вычислить путь нужного файла:

```
from pathlib import Path

base_directory = Path(__file__).parent

...

picture_2 = {
    'picture': open(base_directory / 'files/patrik.jpg', 'rb')
}
```